# Interactive Ruby error return Method Name in error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, interactive

The command line is returning an error with the method name as soon as enter is pressed after typing 'end'

Error

[image]

Comment: the image you posted.. where is the error ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error, but simply the name of the method which was defined.
Just continue :)

Answer (score 1):

This is no error, you can call now:

```
MyAdd(5, 5)
```

and it will work, this shows only that it was defined.